# Django M2M Filter QuerySet With Exact M2M Set

Tags: django, many-to-many

Suppose I have the following 3 models, where each of 2 of the models have a M2M relationship with the 3rd model.

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
    third_model = models.ManyToMany('ThirdModel')


class SecondModel(models.Model):
    third_model = models.ManyToMany('ThirdModel')


class ThirdModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

Now, suppose further I have a specific `SecondModel` object and a `FirstModel` `QuerySet`.  I need to filter the `QuerySet` so that the resulting `QuerySet` contains only the `FirstModel` objects that have the exact same `M2M` relationship set with `ThirdModel` as the `SecondModel` object's `M2M` relationship set with `ThirdModel`.

```
def some_filtering_method(first_model_qs, second_model):
    third_models_set = second_model.third_model_set.all()
    first_model_ids = list()
    for third_model in third_models_set:
        first_model_ids.append(
            [first_model.pk
             for first_model in third_model.first_model_set.all()])
    intersection_of_first_model_ids = get_intersection(first_model_ids)
    return first_model_qs.filter(pk__in=intersection_of_first_model_ids)
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this in Django?  I tried the following with no success (after reviewing the raw query it's obvious why it won't work).

```
import operator

from django.db.models import Q


def some_filtering_method(first_model_qs, second_model):
    return first_model_qs.filter(
        reduce(
            operator.and_, 
            (Q(third_model_set__contains=x) 
             for x in second_model.third_model_set.all())
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the most Pythonic way, but the probably the most *Djangonic* way would be the use of a [custom Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/).

In Django 1.6 and prior, you need to set up the Manager and QuerySet separately:

```
class SharedM2MSetQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def shared(self):
        pass
        # your code here

class SharedM2MSetManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PersonQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def shared(self,other):
        return self.get_queryset().shared(other)

    class FirstModel(models.Model):
        third_model = models.ManyToMany('ThirdModel')
        manager = SharedM2MSetQuerySet.as_manager()
```

If you are using Django 1.7, you can shortcut a lot of this by using a [QuerySet as a Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#creating-manager-with-queryset-methods), like so:

```
class SharedM2MSetQuerySet(models.Manager):
    def shared(self,other):
        pass
        # your code here

class FirstModel(models.Model):
    third_model = models.ManyToMany('ThirdModel')
    manager = SharedM2MSetQuerySet.as_manager()

class SecondModel(models.Model):
    third_model = models.ManyToMany('ThirdModel')

class ThirdModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

In both cases, this then allows you do do things like:

```
my_obj = SecondModel.objects.first()
for i in FirstModel.objects.shared(my_obj):
    do_the_thing(i)
```

Comment: Just for clarification when you say "your code here", which code are you referring to?  The `some_filtering_method` code in my question or some custom code that needs to be determined?